# Linking to Boost.Signals using Xcode

Tags: xcode, boost, linker

I can't for the life of me get Xcode to link to Boost.Signals properly. I've built Boost using MacPorts, and I even went as far as downloading Boost myself and manually building it.

I've set the Library Search Paths to include /opt/local/lib, and I've added "-lboost_signals-mt" to the Other Linker Flags. I've tried dragging and dropping the libraries into the Frameworks folder. I've tried adding the libraries to the build target.

I always get the error that the "file is not of required architecture."

Just to make sure the problem was with Xcode, I went ahead and wrote a makefile to build the project--it works fine, using the same linker flag shown above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the target architecture in your Xcode project.  It looks like you're trying to compile a universal binary.  Unless you explicitly ask for it, boost will be built for the architecture of the build machine only.